# Counting in sql and subas

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I have the following code

```
select ID, count(*) from 
( select ID, service type from database
group by 1,2) suba 
group by 1 
having count (*) > 1
```

And I get a table where i see the IDs and a count of changes. Similar to this

```
ID     |   Count(*)
5675   |   2
5695   |   3
5855   |   2
5625   |   4
5725   |   3
```

Can someone explain to me how to count all the count(*) into groups such that i get a table similar to...

```
count (*)   | number
2 | 2
3 | 2
4 | 1
```

and so forth. Can someone also explain to be me what suba means?

MY NEWEST CODE:

```
select suba.id, count(*) from 
( select id, service_type from table_name
group by 1,2) as  suba
group by 1 
having count (*) > 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure what 'change once', 'change twice', 'change three' means, and where 56, 60, and 34 are even coming from given your sample data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but I think this should work

```
 select NoOfChanges, count (*) from
 ( 
     select suba.id, count(*) as NoOfChanges from 
      ( select id, service_type from table_name
       group by 1,2) as  suba
       group by 1 
       having count (*) > 1 
    )
 subtableb
 group by NoOfChanges
```

You can think of that as

```
select NoOfChanges, count (*) from subtableb
group by NoOfChanges
```

but subtableb isn't a real table, but the results from your previous query

Answer (score 0):

`suba` is the alias of the subquery. Every table or subquery needs a unique name or an alias so you can refer to it in other parts of the query (and disambiguate). Note there is a missing implicit `AS` between the closing parenthesis and "suba".